# const, let or none for addeventlistener, what would be correct?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

So I have been searching around, but was unable to find any mentions of this.

If I want to add an "EventListener" to an element, what would be the "correct" way?

```
    const myHtmlElement = document.getElementById("my-id");
    myHtmlElement.addEventListener("change", function(e){ do stuff });
```

Or should i use let for this instead? Since I'm "adding" an eventlistener?

Or would it more correct to simple do

```
document.getElementById("my-id").addEventListener("change", function(e){ do stuff });
```

Comment: I think it depends on point of view of reuse of variables

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference. You're probably never using the variable again.

Comment: doesn't really matter both are doing the same thing if you want more readability then go with first probably

Comment: But if i set it to const, isn't that going against what it should be? Something which you do not change, or manipulate. Isn't adding an eventlisterner doing exactly that?

Comment: [`const`](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-const) here only means that you can not reassign anything else to `myHtmlElement`. Since it is not a base value but more of a reference, the element or rather its properties and attributes itself can still change.

Comment: You're not _overwriting_ the variable - you're changing a property of the element _assigned_ to that variable. (I prefer the first version - it helps keeps lines short and readable.)

Comment: @Andy why not use `let` instead?

Comment: Like @Barmar said it makes no difference. It's a personal dev decision but I always use `const` these days except when I need to change the value of that variable at some point, and then I would use `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use const since you are not doing reassignment of variable.

Const does not mean the value it holds is immutable, it means that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

First approach has better readability so go with that definitely.